# How to use pspasswd with -u argument

Tags: windows

I want to use pspasswd utility to change password on all of computers on LAN. I googled and came to know following would help

```
pspasswd \\* -u AdminUserName -p AdminPassword Username NewPassword
```

but when I execute this command I get following output

PsPasswd v1.23 - Local and remote password changer
Copyright (C) 2003-2010 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

PsPasswd changes passwords on a local or remote system.

Usage for local accounts:
  pspasswd [\[computer[,computer,[,...]]|@file] [-u Username [-p Password]]]
      Account [NewPassword]
Usage for domain accounts:
  pspasswd Domain\Account [NewPassword]

```
 computer    Computer or computers on which the local account exists. If
             you omit the computer name, the local computer is assumed.
             If you specify a wildcard (\\*), PsPasswd runs the
             command on all computers in the current domain or workgroup.
 @file       PsPasswd will change the password on the computers listed
             in the file.
 -u          Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
 -p          Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
             you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
 Domain      Specifies name of the domain of the target account.
 Account     Specifies name of the account for password change.
 NewPassword New password. If omitted a NULL password is applied.
```

I don't seem to find if I've written something wrong in the syntax. If someone can please figure out the problem.

Comment: I take it your in a work group, not a domain?

Comment: Yes it's in a workgroup, but I think its a bug in pspasswd v 1.23 and I can't find any perivious version of it. see this http://forum.sysinternals.com/pspasswd-v123-have-been-found-a-bug_topic28982.html